# Tikz - how can I remove the short vertical lines in a tree

Tags: tikz-trees, tikz-node

I have the following codes.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{qtree}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[margin=2cm,left=2cm,includefoot]{geometry}\linespread{1.5}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{caption}
%\captionsetup[table]{position=bottom}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\newcolumntype{K}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\tikzset{every tree node/.style={align=center, anchor=north}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

    \Tree [.CP [.{} \node(c){}; ] [.C' [.TP [.DP_{1} \edge[roof]; \node(A){older sister}; ] [.T' [.VP [.DP\\ \node(a){$t_{1}$}; ] [.V' [.DP \edge[roof]; \node(C){which one food}; ] [.V\\ \node(b){make}; ] ] ] [.T \node(B){}; ] ] ] [.C\\{[+Q]} ] ] ]
   \draw[semithick, <-] (A) to [bend right=58] (a);
   \draw[loosely dotted, <-] (B) to [bend left=58] (b);
   \draw[dotted, <-] (c) to [bend right=58] (C);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

They give me a tree looks like:

[image]

Could someone please tell me how can I remove the short vertical line under the node in the top left corner and under DP and T? Thx!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm,left=2cm,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\tikzset{every tree node/.style={align=center, anchor=north}}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\linespread{1.5}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\linespread{0.9}
    \Tree [.CP [.\node(c){}; ] % <---
              [.C' [.TP [.DP_{1} \edge[roof]; \node(A){older sister}; ]
                        [.T' [.VP [.\node(a){DP\\$t_{1}$}; ] % <---
                                 [.V' [.DP \edge[roof]; \node(C){which one food}; ]
                                      [.V\\ \node(b){make}; ]
                                ]
                            ]
                            [.\node(B){T}; ] % <---
                        ]
                   ]
                   [.C\\{[+Q]} ]
              ]
          ]
   \draw[semithick, <-] (A) to [bend right=58] (a);
   \draw[loosely dotted, <-] (B) to [bend left=58] (b);
   \draw[dotted, <-] (c) to [bend right=58] (C);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @erda, if you will not receive better answer, you should consider to accept this (by clicking on check mark on the top left side of answer) :-)

Comment: Am I meant to get a vertical line above 'make' when I run this?

Comment: @cfr, this is (to me) not clear from op question nor code. in answer i consider that not, however, looking now, above `make` should be vertical lines. so far op is satisfied with the solution without this line.

Comment: What I meant was, when I compiled your code, I got a line, but your output doesn't show a line.

Answer (score 2):

A very simple Forest translation (nothing fancy!) just because.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\usepackage{gb4e}
% \linespread{1.5}% don't do this - use setspace if required

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    fit=band
  },
  before typesetting nodes={
    where content={}{content=\strut}{}
  }
  [CP 
    [, name=c ] 
    [C' 
      [TP 
        [DP_{1} 
          [older sister, name=A, roof]
        ]
        [T' 
          [VP 
            [DP\\$t_{1}$, name=a ]
            [V' 
              [DP 
                [which one food, name=C, roof]
              ]
              [V
                [make, name=b]
              ]
            ]
          ]
          [T,  name=B ]
        ]
      ]
      [C\\{[+Q]}]
    ]
  ]
  \draw[semithick, <-] (A) to [bend right=58] (a);
  \draw[loosely dotted, <-] (B) to [bend left=58] (b);
  \draw[dotted, <-] (c.center) to [bend right=58] (C);
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: simple Forest translation]

Comment: +1! i'm still not familiar with "tricks" like `before typesetting nodes=...`. i still learning `forest` :-)

Comment: @Zarko You could just use `delay` if that makes more sense to you. Either would work here.